# First column in pandas dataframe is not a column?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
>>df
               Column1    Column2
   vo1                          
    102        0.023002           0
    301     3571.662104           0
    302     1346.910261           0
    ...
```

So there are three columns? But:

```
>>df.dtypes
Column1      float64
Column2      float64
dtype: object
```

So its two columns? What is the first one (`vo`) called? I want to use it for a merge but when i do i get error saying there is no column named `vo`.

Comment: It is called an index.  You can assign to it a new column (and thus create a new monotonic index) by calling `dfimp.reset_index(inplace = True)`.  If you want to lose the old index and just get a new monotonic index, pass `drop = True) into the reset index function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called `index`, check it by:

```
print (df.index)
Int64Index([102, 301, 302], dtype='int64', name='vo_11')
```

Also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

> The axis labeling information in pandas objects serves many purposes:
>
> -Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators, important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console display
> -Enables automatic and explicit data alignment
> -Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set

If need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by indexes of both `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Notice:

*For matching need indexes of same types - both `int` or `object` (obviously `string`)*

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Column1': {302: 10, 301: 21, 102: 2}, 
'Column2': {302: 0, 301: 0, 102: 0}})
print (df1)
    Column1  Column2
102        2        0
301       21        0
302       10        0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Column1': {302: 4, 301: 5, 304: 6}, 
'Column2': {302: 0, 301: 0, 304: 0}})
print (df2)
     Column1  Column2
301        5        0
302        4        0
304        6        0
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df)
     Column1_x  Column2_x  Column1_y  Column2_y
301         21          0          5          0
302         10          0          4          0

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
print (df)
     Column1_x  Column2_x  Column1_y  Column2_y
102        2.0        0.0        NaN        NaN
301       21.0        0.0        5.0        0.0
302       10.0        0.0        4.0        0.0
304        NaN        NaN        6.0        0.0

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) 
print (df)
     Column1  Column2  Column1  Column2
102      2.0      0.0      NaN      NaN
301     21.0      0.0      5.0      0.0
302     10.0      0.0      4.0      0.0
304      NaN      NaN      6.0      0.0

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner') 
print (df)
     Column1  Column2  Column1  Column2
301       21        0        5        0
302       10        0        4        0
```